# Compilation error in Cython

Tags: cython

I installed cython in lubuntu and trying complie 'hello World' program using terminal command

```
python3 setup.py build_ext
```

but gcc returns [compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjGq4.png).
Here is my setup.py code

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize      

setup(

    ext_modules = cythonize("cython.pyx")
)
```

and cython.pyx code

```
print("hello World")
```

Comment: Please include your code and error messages as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Please edit your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A problem could be naming your pyx-file "cython". Try to give it another name.

Answer (score 0):

got it by using terminal command

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

and changed setup.py to

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["cython.pyx"])]

setup(
    name = 'Hello world app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```